# How to read child property in Angular2?

Tags: angular

I have angular router implemented.

```
<header><header>
<router-outlet><router-outlet>
```

My header is simple:

```
  <li [ng-class]="{active: active1}"></li>
  <li [ng-class]="{active: active2}"></li>
  <li [ng-class]="{active: active3}"></li>
```

How to set up these `active*`s in children so that `Header` component can mark a corresponding class as active?

Comment: Hey @squixy what you are trying to do is not yet implemented, see issue [#4452](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/4452).

Comment: you want to use [ng-class] like this http://plnkr.co/edit/TRm7wXKWKqEiue4ZeJl7?p=preview ?

Comment: @EricMartinez thanks for linking that. This is exactly what I need.

Comment: @PardeepJain I know the case you showed here, but this is inside one view, I need to propagate variable from children to parent.

Comment: ohh okay whenever i have done with your problem ill let you know about this.